Why is GeoServer wanting the key "Levels" in my ___regex.properties files when trying to make Image Mosaic?

Geoserver 2.25.3
Java 11
Linux/RHEL 9
Tomcat 9.x
PostgreSQL 15 w/ PostGIS

I have am really struggling to get an Image Mosaic store published; every time I attempt to do so I get a message back where it appears to be looking for the key Levels on all my regex files and even indexer.properties for extracting custom dimension values from the file name of the GeoTIFFs. It shouldn't be looking for a key Levels in regex or indexer files, it should only find that in the file GeoServer is supposed to generate itself: <directory>.properties. It creates an empty table with the appropriate headings based on my indexer.properties but does not populate it. It does not manage to create the sample_image.dat file or the <directory>.properties file. All my GeoTIFFs and .properties files are in the same directory which is /geoserver_data/data/ddd/.
The name of a GeoTIFF is structured like this: bcc_csm2_mr_ssp245_dbcca_daymet_prms_runoff_2020_2059_annual.tif
The regex files would split the filename into these attributes which should load into the Postgis table:
(bcc_csm2_mr)(ssp245)(dbcca)(daymet)(prms)(runoff)(2020_2059)(annual)
This is my indexer.properties. I have put a bunch of carriage returns in so you can actually read it, but on the server the file only puts the three different keys on new lines (Schema, PropertyCollectors, and AdditionalDomainAttributes).
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,
location:String,
clm_model:String,
em_scenario:String,
downscale:String,
meteor_force:String,
model_grid:String,
clm_variable:String,
clm_period:String,
time_period:String
PropertyCollectors=StringFileNameExtractorSPI[clmmodelregex](clm_model),
StringFileNameExtractorSPI[emscenarioregex](em_scenario),
StringFileNameExtractorSPI[downscaleregex](downscale),
StringFileNameExtractorSPI[meteorforceregex](meteor_force),
StringFileNameExtractorSPI[modelgridregex](model_grid),
StringFileNameExtractorSPI[clmvariableregex](clm_variable),
StringFileNameExtractorSPI[clmperiodregex](clm_period),
StringFileNameExtractorSPI[timeperiodregex](time_period)
AdditionalDomainAttributes=clm_model,
em_scenario,
downscale,
meteor_force,
model_grid,
clm_variable,
clm_period,
time_period

As you can see, I have many regex files. I am uncertain if GeoServer has some sort of limit on custom dimensions that's maybe causing the weird errors. I can't find anything about that in the documentation though. Am I misunderstanding how custom dimensions can be used?
Most of the log file using GeoTools Developer logging:
It repeats this for every .properties file it finds in the directory:
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Trying to load properties file from URL:file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/emscenarioregex.properties
09 Aug 23:44:29 INFO   [gce.imagemosaic] - Required key Levels not found.
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723256216217
length:27

It then continues to this...
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723261418120
length:776
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723256216219
length:91
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723256216217
length:22
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723256216219
length:25
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723256216217
length:27
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723256216219
length:23
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723256216217
length:107
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723256216217
length:25
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723256216217
length:95
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723256216217
length:84
09 Aug 23:44:29 INFO   [gce.imagemosaic] - Now indexing file bcc_csm2_mr_ssp245_dbcca_daymet_vic4_tmax_2060_2099_annual.tif
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Thread Name http-nio-8080-exec-2
class org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicEventHandlers
Now indexing file bcc_csm2_mr_ssp245_dbcca_daymet_vic4_tmax_2060_2099_annual.tif
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.arcgrid] - ArcGridFormatFactory is available.
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.arcgrid] - Creating a new ArcGriFormat.
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [referencing.factory] - Failure in the primary factory: No code "EPSG:4326" from authority "European Petroleum Survey Group" found for object of type "interface org.geotools.api.referencing.IdentifiedObject". Now trying the fallback factory...
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [imageio.geotiff] - Logging tiePoints:
Tie point
    Raster Space point (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    Model Space point (-125.02083333334, 53.020833333333606, 0.0)
Logging pixScales:
Pixel Scale
    scaleX=0.041666666666671404 is set? true
    scaleY=0.04166666666667042 is set? true
    scaleZ=0.0 is set? false


09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Create schema: CREATE TABLE "public"."ddd" ( "fid" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, "the_geom" geometry, "location" VARCHAR, "clm_model" VARCHAR, "em_scenario" VARCHAR, "downscale" VARCHAR, "meteor_force" VARCHAR, "model_grid" VARCHAR, "clm_variable" VARCHAR, "clm_period" VARCHAR, "time_period" VARCHAR ) 
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - ALTER TABLE "public"."ddd" ALTER COLUMN "the_geom" TYPE geometry (POLYGON, 4326);
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE INDEX "spatial_ddd_the_geom" ON "public"."ddd" USING GIST ("the_geom")
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Metadata table GT_PK_METADATA was not found
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Getting information about primary keys of ddd
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Grabbing table pk metadata: SELECT "fid" FROM "public"."ddd" WHERE 0=1
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Geometry type check; SELECT TYPE FROM geometry_columns WHERE F_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public' AND F_TABLE_NAME = 'ddd' AND f_geometry_column = 'the_geom' 
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Geography srid check; SELECT SRID FROM GEOGRAPHY_COLUMNS WHERE F_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public' AND F_TABLE_NAME = 'ddd' AND F_GEOGRAPHY_COLUMN = 'the_geom' 
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Geometry srid check; SELECT SRID FROM GEOMETRY_COLUMNS WHERE F_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public' AND F_TABLE_NAME = 'ddd' AND F_GEOMETRY_COLUMN = 'the_geom' 
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Geography srid check; SELECT COORD_DIMENSION FROM GEOGRAPHY_COLUMNS WHERE F_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public' AND F_TABLE_NAME = 'ddd' AND F_GEOGRAPHY_COLUMN = 'the_geom' 
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Geometry srid check; SELECT COORD_DIMENSION FROM GEOMETRY_COLUMNS WHERE F_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public' AND F_TABLE_NAME = 'ddd' AND F_GEOMETRY_COLUMN = 'the_geom' 
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [imagemosaic.catalog] - BBOXFilterExtractor::extractBasicProperties(): geometryPropertyName is set to 'the_geom'.
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [properties.string] - No matches found for this property extractor:
09 Aug 23:44:29 ERROR  [gce.imagemosaic] - Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:374)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1310)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.properties.string.StringFileNameExtractor.setProperties(StringFileNameExtractor.java:55)

Other possibly relevant messages:
09 Aug 23:44:29 INFO   [gce.imagemosaic] - Stopping requested at file  1 of 5 files
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Thread Name http-nio-8080-exec-2
class org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicEventHandlers
Stopping requested at file  1 of 5 files
09 Aug 23:44:29 WARN   [gce.imagemosaic] - Failure occurred while collecting the granules
org.apache.commons.io.DirectoryWalker$CancelException: Operation Cancelled

09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Canceled!!!
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Thread Name http-nio-8080-exec-2
class org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicEventHandlers
Canceled!!!
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Indexing complete
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/geoserver_data/data/ddd/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1723261418120
length:776
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - This plugin accepts File, URL or String. The string may describe a File or an URL
org.geotools.api.data.DataSourceException: This plugin accepts File, URL or String. The string may describe a File or an URL

09 Aug 23:44:29 INFO   [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:data/ddd
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:data/ddd and hints Hints:
  REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@4e8925c1                                                                                   
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4f32c1a2[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
System defaults:
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                   
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                   
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                 
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = org.geotools.styling.StyleFactoryImpl@791542c2         
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                   
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                    
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                   
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                      
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@610d3cff

09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
09 Aug 23:44:29 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.


Overtime, I have experienced this same error and same set of logs for a multitude of reasons. I have posted a more thorough overview of everything you need to look at while debugging this cryptic set of logs and errors. See the answer in another one of my questions here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/487131/78698
